# Getting URL inside of EJS layout template?

Tags: express, ejs

My goal is to create a conical URL in the head of my layout doc in .ejs
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element I'd like to do something like the following where I check URL structure and then change how I format that, but I'm assuming the window object doesn't exist at this stage in EJS while it's being templated. I know I could pass the URL on route, but it's a bit late for that and I'm wondering if there's a way I could do this or something like it in the head section of my layout?

```
<% if(window.location.href.indexOf("review")){ %>
   <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/bestTools" />
 <% } else{ %>  
   <link rel="canonical" href="<% window.location.href %>" />
<% } %>
```